# SQL Server - Calculating Distance Between Two Latitude's & Longitude's

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Using SQL Server 2014.

I'm trying to get SQL Server to calculate the distance, in Kilometres, Miles and Nautical Miles between airports from around the world. Mostly, the method below works, but it appears to fail when the distance goes over 10,000Km (Although this is just an assumption).

```
    DECLARE @Radius_Km AS FLOAT
DECLARE @Radius_Mi AS FLOAT
DECLARE @Radius_Nm AS FLOAT
DECLARE @Pi AS FLOAT
DECLARE @D2R AS FLOAT

SET @Radius_Km = '6370.97327862'
SET @Radius_Mi = '3958.73926185'
SET @Radius_Nm = '3440.05036642'
SET @Pi = '3.14159265358979'
SET @D2R = @Pi / 180;


WITH RawData AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Sched.AirlineName, Sched.AirlineIATA, Sched.AirlineICAO, Sched.FlightNo,

            Sched.DepartureAirportName, Sched.DepartureAirportIATA, DepAprt.AirportICAO AS [DepartureAirportICAO], 

            DepAprt.Latitude AS [DepartureAirportLatitude], DepAprt.Longitude AS [DepartureAirportLongitude],

            Sched.ArrivalAirportName, Sched.ArrivalAirportIATA, ArrAprt.AirportICAO AS [ArrivalAirportICAO], 

            ArrAprt.Latitude AS [ArrivalAirportLatitude], ArrAprt.Longitude AS [ArrivalAirportLongitude]

    FROM VAS_Live.dbo.RawData_FR24 AS Sched

        LEFT JOIN VAS_Live.dbo.ReferenceData_Airports AS DepAprt
            ON Sched.DepartureAirportIATA = DepAprt.AirportIATA

        LEFT JOIN VAS_Live.dbo.ReferenceData_Airports AS ArrAprt
            ON Sched.ArrivalAirportIATA = ArrAprt.AirportIATA

),

RadianConvert AS
(
    SELECT *,

        ((DepartureAirportLatitude / 180) * @Pi) AS [DALat],
        ((DepartureAirportLongitude / 180) * @Pi) AS [DALon],
        ((ArrivalAirportLatitude / 180) * @Pi) AS [AALat],
        ((ArrivalAirportLongitude / 180) * @Pi) AS [AALon]

    FROM RawData
),

CentralSphericalAngle AS
(
    SELECT *,

    (Sin(DALat) * Sin(AALat)) + (Cos(DALat) * Cos(AALat) * Cos(AALon - DALon)) AS [Test]

    FROM RadianConvert
),

TestCTE AS
(
    SELECT *,

        @Radius_Mi * ATAN(SQRT(1 - POWER(Test, 2)) / Test) AS [Test2]

    FROM CentralSphericalAngle
)

SELECT *
FROM TestCTE
WHERE DepartureAirportIATA = 'LHR' AND ArrivalAirportIATA = 'SIN'
```

For the example above, the LHR Lat & Lon are as follows:

51.4775
-0.461389

The SIN Lat & Long are as follows:

1.35019
103.994

I already know the distance is roughly:

Km - 10,883

Mi - 6,762

Nm - 5,876

Any idea why SQL is giving me -5674?

I used to use VBA and Excel to calculate this data, which worked. I noticed that the Arrival AALat & DALon are incorrectly calculating when converting to Radians - but I have no idea why.

Thanks

Matthew

Comment: 1) Use `GEOGRAPHY` datatype 2) Use [`.STDistance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933808.aspx) 3) Avoid complex formulas, recalculation between radians/degress and so on

Comment: Geography datatype takes an absolute age to calculate. When I need this done for thousands of rows - it just isn't a solution I'm afraid - unless you have any code you would like me to specifically try and report back?

Comment: What formula are you using here?  It doesn't look like haversine to me.  For spatial, try this: SELECT *, GEOGRAPHY::POINT(DepAprt.Latitude, DepAprt.Longitude, 4326).STDistance(GEOGRAPHY::Point(ArrAprt.Latitude, ArrAprt.Longitude,4326)) FROM RawData

Comment: Ok, tried this and I get 10887730.8812865 as the answer. Any idea what I'm supposed to do with this to display it as Km, Mi and Nm?

Comment: "Geography takes an absolute age to calculate". Do you have benchmarks there? My experience has been the exact opposite. Especially if you already have geography points created and stored. Which, given a quick glance at your schema, you most certainly could (as a computed column if you want to keep Latitude and Longitude).

Comment: After some testing - it doesn't appear to be as slow as I thought it would. The Lat & Long's are in a FLOAT column. I read from other posts that the Geography Data Type was not as fast as the solution listed below - however, the below is still returning incorrect results for large distances. Geography does appear to be working though.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate a distance (miles) function  from Lat & Lon as by:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[getDistanceFromLatLon](@lat1  float, @lon1 float, @lat2 float, @lon2 float)   
Returns float   
AS  
BEGIN 
 Declare  @R  int  
    set @R= 6371;   

    Declare @a float  
    Declare  @c  float  
    Declare  @d  float  

    Declare @dLat float;  
    Declare @dLon float;  
    declare @DegToRad float
BEGIN

    set @DegToRad= (select PI() / 180)
    set @dLat = (@lat2 - @lat1)* @DegToRad;   
    set @dLon = (@lon2 - @lon1)* @DegToRad;  
    set @a =   sin(@dLat / 2) * sin(@dLat / 2) +  
   cos((@lat1)* @DegToRad) * cos((@lat2)* @DegToRad) *  
    sin(@dLon / 2) * sin(@dLon / 2) ;  
    set @c = 2 * atn2(sqrt(@a), sqrt(1 - @a));  
    set @d = @R * @c;   
 END  

     return (@d * 0.6214)

END
```

From this function ,

```
DECLARE @Kilimiles float
DECLARE @miles float
DECLARE @nauticalmile float
SET @miles=(SELECT dbo.[getDistanceFromLatLon](51.4775, -0.461389,1.35019 ,103.994))
SET @Kilimiles=@miles * 1.60934
SET @nauticalmile= @miles * 0.868976

SELECT @miles as Mile,@Kilimiles as Kilomile,@nauticalmile as NauticalMile
```